# Observable list from database into choiceBox

Tags: java, mysql

I created an ObservableList that connects to MySQL database and I created a choiceBox. The choiceBox is not displaying the list.

I'm very new to Java. I searched the questions in this forum and I don't understand how to apply those answers to my situation. Most of the information I have been finding relates to a list that is manually defined within the code and that is not my situation since it should be relating to the information within my database. Thank you in advance.

```
public ObservableList<Product> getProductList() {
    initializeDB();
    ObservableList<Product> products = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    try {
        String queryString = "select Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Description, Product_Image,Product_Price,Category_ID, Available_Inventory from product order by Product_Name ";
        ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(queryString);
        while (rset.next()) {
            int productID = rset.getInt(1);
            String productName = rset.getString(2);
            String productDescription = rset.getString(3);
            float productPrice = rset.getFloat(4);
            int availableInventory = rset.getInt(5);

            products.add(new Product(productID, productName, productDescription,productPrice,availableInventory));
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    closeDB();
    return products;

Label ad_productName_label = new Label("Product Name:");
    ChoiceBox ad_productName_choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<Product>();
    ObservableList<Product> products = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ad_productName_choiceBox.getItems().addAll();

    ad_productName_choiceBox.setMaxWidth(300);
```

Comment: Wait... are you creating the `Label` after return statement - which is unreachable? Or is it another method?

Comment: And where are you calling method `getProductList()`?

Comment: Usagi Miyamoto - Maybe that's my issue? Where am I supposed to be calling method getProductList()? This is so confusing to me. I apologize for my ignorance.